# Spark S3 Eventual Consistency Issues

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have several Spark jobs that write data to and read data from S3. Occasionally (about once per week for approximately 3 hours), the Spark jobs will fail with the following exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist.
```

I've uncovered that this is likely due to the consistency model in S3, where list operations are eventually consistent. [S3 Guard](https://hortonworks.com/blog/s3guard-amazon-s3-consistency/) claims to solve this issue, but I'm in a Spark environment that doesn't support that utility.

Has anyone else run into this issue and figured out a reasonable approach for dealing with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are using AWS EMR, they offer consistent EMR.
- if you are using Databricks: they offer a consistency mechanism in their [transactional IO](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/dbio-commit.html)
- Both HDP and CDH ship with S3Guard
- if you are running your own home-rolled spark stack, , move to Hadoop 2.9+ to get S3Guard, even better: Hadoop 3.1 for the zero-rename S3A committer.

Otherwise: don't use S3 as your direct destination of work.

Comment: I believe their transactional IO does; it's what I was thinking of. Added a link to it

Comment: A somewhat related question: `df.write.mode("overwrite").save("s3://...")` triggers a recursive "delete" operation on the s3 location. Assume that location contains a ton of objects, does Spark wait for the deletion to complete? or s3 just marks them as deleted without actually deleting them?

Comment: deletes all. don't know about s3:// ; s3a does a series of bulk DELETE calls. each file to delete uses up one of your 3500 writes that second, so we do more small pages over few big ones, and try not to overload the store https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-16823 . ultimately, manifest formats (iceberg, hudi,, delta lake) are the way to go here

Comment: s3 does async deletes. so i'm still not sure about the consistency there (eg.: read/write-after-delete). and i have another newbie question: how do manifest formats mitigate the quota limit?

Comment: 1. s3 is fully consistent; has been for a few years.
2. manifest formats commit work by writing a single file, so no end of job renames, POSTs of multipart uploads etc.